# Scrapy callback not giving out all results

Tags: python, scrapy

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy import Field

class CrawlingSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "mycrawler"
    allowed_domains = ["service-public.fr"]
    start_urls = ["https://lannuaire.service-public.fr/navigation/mairie?where=71&"]

    COUNT_MAX = 600

    custom_settings = {
        'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': COUNT_MAX
    }

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow="saone-et-loire", deny=["banque_de_france","epide","pole_emploi","mission_local","droit_travail","clic","tribunal_commerce","centre_penitentiaire","laboratoire_departemental","cnftp","ordre_avocats","permanence_juridique","spip","sdjes","onac","ddsp","dmd","commissariat_police","maison_handicapees","sdis","cirfa","prefecture","safer","fr_renov","ddt","sous_pref","point_accueil_numerique","cdg","cg","chambre_notaires","civi","commission_conciliation","bav","fdc","ddva","maia","pmi","sdac","caf","cpam","ddpp","epci","ars_antenne","cij","ad","caue","prefecture_greffe_associations","crib","dd_femmes","demande-de-mise-a-jour","msa","pif","ssti","urssaf","afpa","permanance_juridique","aav","prudhommes","gendarmerie","dreal_ut","anah","greta","canope_atelier","cio","tresorerie","sip","sie","dd_fip","hypotheque","pcb","paierie_departementale","credit_municipal"]), callback="aaa"),
    )

    def aaa(self, response):
        yield {
            "mail": response.css(".send-mail::text").get(),
        }
```

So I want to get email from a website (i'm new to this I looked a tuto on yt) and if i don't put the callback at the end it gives me like 600 results and with the callback I get like 27. Any solutions ?

removing callback ? ig

Answer (score 0):

In it's current state you spider is visiting the `start_url` crawling each of the links that match the regular expression in the allow parameter and then passing each of the requests generated by the those links to your callback `aaa` method which is succesfully extracting the email address from the page and yielding it. I am not certain what all of the strings you have listed in `deny` are meant for.

So your spider is working properly and extracting all of the emails for the first page. If your goal is to extract all of the emails from every page, then you would need to add an additional rule that would automatically navigate to the next page.

For example:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class CrawlingSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "mycrawler"
    allowed_domains = ["service-public.fr"]
    start_urls = ["https://lannuaire.service-public.fr/navigation/mairie?where=71"]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow="saone-et-loire"), callback="aaa"),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=["//li[@class='active']/following-sibling::li/a"]))
    )

    def aaa(self, response):
        yield {
            "mail": response.css(".send-mail::text").get(),
        }
```

The additional Rule I added looks for the "active" link in the pagination list towards the bottom of the page, and then takes the link contained in it's following sibling tag to get the next page link.  And by not adding a callback it simply follows that link and applies the same rules to the response it generates.

Comment: well first ty ! it's getting all the mail and putting them in the terminal but not in the output.json

Comment: @Citron  How are you running the spider?

Comment: scrapy crawl mycrawler @Alexender

Comment: So you need to add an output processor if you want them to be saved to a file... try `scrapy crawl mycrawler -o items.json`

Comment: yeahhh i forgot that even if i did it before i'm dumb ty